# Calculate average number of distinct ID's in a period(1 month,3 months ,6 months, 9 months and 12 months)

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have the following source table(I filled in data only for year 2017 in order to save some space, but you can imagine, that table has data from 2017-2021)

```
EMPL_ID     TIMESTAMP        PART_COL
1       2017-01-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-01-01 00:00:00     M
3       2017-01-01 00:00:00     M
3       2017-01-01 00:00:00     M
1       2017-02-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-02-01 00:00:00     M
3       2017-02-01 00:00:00     M
3       2017-02-01 00:00:00     M
1       2017-03-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-03-01 00:00:00     M
3       2017-03-01 00:00:00     M
1       2017-04-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-04-01 00:00:00     M
3       2017-04-01 00:00:00     M
1       2017-05-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-05-01 00:00:00     M
3       2017-05-01 00:00:00     M
4       2017-05-01 00:00:00     M
5       2017-05-01 00:00:00     M
1       2017-06-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-06-01 00:00:00     M
3       2017-06-01 00:00:00     M
4       2017-06-01 00:00:00     M
4       2017-06-01 00:00:00     M
1       2017-07-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-07-01 00:00:00     M
3       2017-07-01 00:00:00     M
1       2017-08-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-08-01 00:00:00     M
3       2017-08-01 00:00:00     M
1       2017-09-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-09-01 00:00:00     M 
1       2017-10-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-10-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-10-01 00:00:00     M
3       2017-10-01 00:00:00     M
4       2017-10-01 00:00:00     M
1       2017-11-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-11-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-11-01 00:00:00     M
3       2017-11-01 00:00:00     M
1       2017-12-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-12-01 00:00:00     M
2       2017-12-01 00:00:00     M
3       2017-12-01 00:00:00     M
```

I want to calculate the following things:

1. For january I want to calculate 4 things:

- number of unuqie empl_id for january partitioned by PART_COL
- average number of unique empl_id over 3 months(from january until march) partitioned by PART_COL
- average number of unique empl_id over 6 months(from january until june) partitioned by PART_COL
- average number of unique empl_id over 9 months(from january until september) partitioned by PART_COL
- average number of unique empl_id over 12 months(from january until december) partitioned by PART_COL

2. For the rest of the months i want to calculate

- number of unuqie empl_id for a month partitioned by PART_COL

At the end it should look like this:

```
UNIQUE_EMPL_ID  TIMESTAMP_FROM  TIMESTAMP_UNTIL   PART_COL
3,00    2017-01-01 00:00:00 2017-01-01 00:00:00      M
3,00    2017-01-01 00:00:00 2017-03-01 00:00:00      M
3,00    2017-01-01 00:00:00 2017-06-01 00:00:00      M
3,50    2017-01-01 00:00:00 2017-09-01 00:00:00      M
3,20    2017-01-01 00:00:00 2017-12-01 00:00:00      M
3,08    2017-02-01 00:00:00 2017-02-01 00:00:00      M
3,00    2017-03-01 00:00:00 2017-03-01 00:00:00      M
3,00    2017-04-01 00:00:00 2017-04-01 00:00:00      M
5,00    2017-05-01 00:00:00 2017-05-01 00:00:00      M
```

and so until 12 month.

I have come up with the following query:

```
SELECT
count(distinct empl_id ) as UNIQUE_EMPL_ID
,TIMESTAMP_COL as TIMESTAMP_FROM
,TIMESTAMP_COL as TIMESTAMP_UNTIL
from source_table
WHERE PART_COLUMN = 'M'
group by TIMESTAMP_COL,PART_COLUMN

union all

SELECT
count(distinct empl_id ) as UNIQUE_EMPL_ID
,TIMESTAMP_COL as TIMESTAMP_FROM
,add_months(TIMESTAMP_COL,2) as TIMESTAMP_UNTIL
,avg(count( distinct empl_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY PART_COLUMN ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_COL ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) as UNIQUE_EMPL_ID
from source_table
WHERE PART_COLUMN = 'M'
group by TIMESTAMP_COL,PART_COLUMN


union all

SELECT
count(distinct empl_id ) as UNIQUE_EMPL_ID
,TIMESTAMP_COL as TIMESTAMP_FROM
,add_months(TIMESTAMP_COL,5) as TIMESTAMP_UNTIL
,avg(count( distinct empl_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY PART_COLUMN ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_COL ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING) as UNIQUE_EMPL_ID
from source_table
WHERE PART_COLUMN = 'M'
group by TIMESTAMP_COL,PART_COLUMN

union all

SELECT
count(distinct empl_id ) as UNIQUE_EMPL_ID
,TIMESTAMP_COL as TIMESTAMP_FROM
,add_months(TIMESTAMP_COL,8) as TIMESTAMP_UNTIL
,avg(count( distinct empl_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY PART_COLUMN ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_COL ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 8 FOLLOWING) as UNIQUE_EMPL_ID
from source_table
WHERE PART_COLUMN = 'M'
group by TIMESTAMP_COL,PART_COLUMN

union all

SELECT
count(distinct empl_id ) as UNIQUE_EMPL_ID
,TIMESTAMP_COL as TIMESTAMP_FROM
,add_months(TIMESTAMP_COL,11) as TIMESTAMP_UNTIL
,avg(count( distinct empl_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY PART_COLUMN ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_COL ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 11 FOLLOWING) as UNIQUE_EMPL_ID
from source_table
WHERE PART_COLUMN = 'M'
group by TIMESTAMP_COL,PART_COLUMN
```

Question is: can this result be achieved by more efficient query?

Comment: Yes. This is possible. Please do not delete this post as I work on the answer. I had a solution for the question you asked earlier today but you deleted the question.

Comment: @EJEgyed I am sorry about that. Just wanted to reformulate question in a bit nicer format.

Comment: @DY92 You may just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68349478/edit) your question even to reformulate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By first creating a table using a Common Table Expression, you can then use the data there to use the `UNPIVOT` function to calculate the totals for each period, then a simple select from the CTE to get your monthly data.

Any filters (WHERE clauses) to limit the data that needs to be returned should be added to the `unique_emps` CTE below.

```sql
WITH
    sample_data (emp_id, timestamp, part_col)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-01-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, DATE '2017-01-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, DATE '2017-01-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, DATE '2017-02-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-02-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, DATE '2017-02-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, DATE '2017-02-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, DATE '2017-03-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-03-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, DATE '2017-03-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, DATE '2017-04-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-04-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, DATE '2017-04-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, DATE '2017-05-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-05-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, DATE '2017-05-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, DATE '2017-05-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5, DATE '2017-05-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, DATE '2017-06-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-06-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, DATE '2017-06-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, DATE '2017-06-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, DATE '2017-06-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, DATE '2017-07-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-07-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, DATE '2017-07-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, DATE '2017-08-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-08-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, DATE '2017-08-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, DATE '2017-09-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-09-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, DATE '2017-10-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-10-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-10-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, DATE '2017-10-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, DATE '2017-10-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, DATE '2017-11-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-11-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-11-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, DATE '2017-11-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, DATE '2017-12-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-12-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, DATE '2017-12-01', 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, DATE '2017-12-01', 'M' FROM DUAL),
    --Query starts here
    --Filters should be added to the unique_emps Common Table Expression to limit data returned
    unique_emps (mon, part_col, distinct_emps)
    AS
        (  SELECT timestamp, part_col, COUNT (DISTINCT emp_id)
             FROM sample_data
         GROUP BY timestamp, part_col)
  SELECT timestamp_from,
         ADD_MONTHS (timestamp_from, period)     AS timestamp_until,
         AVG (period_people)                     AS avg_number_of_people,
         part_col
    FROM (SELECT TRUNC (mon, 'Y')
                     AS timestamp_from,
                 part_col,
                 CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mon, 'Q')) <= 1 THEN distinct_emps END
                     period_people1,
                 CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mon, 'Q')) <= 2 THEN distinct_emps END
                     period_people2,
                 CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mon, 'Q')) <= 3 THEN distinct_emps END
                     period_people3,
                 CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mon, 'Q')) <= 4 THEN distinct_emps END
                     period_people4
            FROM unique_emps)
         UNPIVOT (period_people
                 FOR period
                 IN (period_people1 AS 2,
                    period_people2 AS 5,
                    period_people3 AS 8,
                    period_people4 AS 11))
GROUP BY timestamp_from, period, part_col
UNION ALL
SELECT mon, mon, distinct_emps, part_col FROM unique_emps
ORDER BY timestamp_from, timestamp_until, avg_number_of_people;
```

### Result

```
   TIMESTAMP_FROM    TIMESTAMP_UNTIL                        AVG_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE    PART_COL
_________________ __________________ ___________________________________________ ___________
01-JAN-17         01-JAN-17                                                    3 M
01-JAN-17         01-MAR-17                                                    3 M
01-JAN-17         01-JUN-17                                                  3.5 M
01-JAN-17         01-SEP-17             3.22222222222222222222222222222222222222 M
01-JAN-17         01-DEC-17                                                 3.25 M
01-FEB-17         01-FEB-17                                                    3 M
01-MAR-17         01-MAR-17                                                    3 M
01-APR-17         01-APR-17                                                    3 M
01-MAY-17         01-MAY-17                                                    5 M
01-JUN-17         01-JUN-17                                                    4 M
01-JUL-17         01-JUL-17                                                    3 M
01-AUG-17         01-AUG-17                                                    3 M
01-SEP-17         01-SEP-17                                                    2 M
01-OCT-17         01-OCT-17                                                    4 M
01-NOV-17         01-NOV-17                                                    3 M
01-DEC-17         01-DEC-17                                                    3 M
```